# Graph ( Network ) creation from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to build a relationship graph (network) from few dataframe columns.

For example my data points look like this:

```
graph_strucure = {
                   'node_a' : ['a','b','c','a','b','c'] , 
                   'node_b' : ['r','g','m','g','r','r'],
                   'edges': [['aa','bb','cc','dd'],['cc','rr'],['ae','rt'],['ew'],['rtr','tyu'],['df','yu']]
                  }
```

I want to build a network using node_a and node_b where edges are relationship between them.

What I have tried so far :

Count unique values:

```
unique_nodes = list(set(graph_strucure['node_a'] + graph_strucure['node_b']))
```

convert into one_hot :

```
one_hot_encoding = [np.zeros(len(unique_nodes)) for i in range(len(unique_nodes))]

tuples = list(zip(graph_strucure['node_a'] ,graph_strucure['node_b']))

for k in range(len(unique_nodes)):
    node = unique_nodes[k]
    for m in tuples:
        if node == m[0]:
            one_hot_encoding[k][unique_nodes.index(m[1])] = 1

        elif node == m[1]:
            one_hot_encoding[k][unique_nodes.index(m[0])] = 1

one_hot_encoding = np.matrix(one_hot_encoding)
```

build network using networkx:

```
G = from_numpy_matrix(one_hot_encoding, create_using=DiGraph())
pos = spring_layout(G)

draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color='lightblue')
draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,width=1.0,alpha=0.5)

labels = dict(zip(G.nodes(), G.nodes()))
draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels, font_size=12)
plt.axis('off')
```

[image]

Now from here if i want adjacency matrix I can use:

```
nx.adj_matrix(G)
```

But I am little bit confuse about this approach because if I am right then i can use that one hot encoding as adjacency matrix?

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone kindly give me some advice on how to efficiently build network from those data points, adjacency matrix and assign edges relationship on edges.

Comment: Why do you think you need the one-hot encoding?